# Image list, removing reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently I'm using an ImageList control, attempting to copy files off the network and overwrite whats on the ImageList. However, when I try to copy the images once the List has be populated I'm unable since the images are loaded. I've tried using .Dispose() and .Images.Clear() but from what I've read nothing removes the reference to the Image itself so it can be replaced.

```
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        imageList2.Images.Clear();


        int i = 1500;
        string fileName,sourcePath,targetPath,destFile = string.Empty;
        Image img = null;
        int counter = 0;
        bool exists = false;
        string image = string.Empty;
        MiscManager MM = new MiscManager();
        //filePath = MM.GetBobbinImagePath();
        filePath = @"C:\Program Files\Images";
        sourcePath = @"\\network Images";
        targetPath = filePath;

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath)) 
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

            foreach (string n in files)
            {
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(n);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(n, destFile, true);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File in use",fileName);
                }

            }
        }

        do
        {
            if (i < 10)
            {
                fileName = "000" + Convert.ToString(i);
            }
            else if (i > 10 && i < 100)
            {
                fileName = "00" + Convert.ToString(i);
            }
            else if (i >= 100 && i < 1000)
            {
                fileName = "0" + Convert.ToString(i);
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = Convert.ToString(i);
            }

            image = filePath + fileName + ".bmp";
            exists = File.Exists(image);

            if (exists)
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(image);

                imageList1.Images.Add(img);
                imageList2.Images.Add(img);

                imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(counter, Convert.ToString(i) + ".bmp");
                imageList2.Images.SetKeyName(counter, Convert.ToString(i) + ".bmp");
                counter++;
            }


            i++;
        } while (i < 10000);
```

I don't know much about an Image list so any assistance is always greatly appreciated. Doing this in c# and VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MemoryStream` so your image doesn't hold on to the reference to the file stream:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(image))
{
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I cant try it at the moment but I will try it first thing in the morning